# JQuery Mobile : ajax works locally but not online

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

I encounter a strange issue, my code works in my computer but when I point my ajax url to remote server, it always failure.

My code as below:

```
    $.ajax({
             url: web_url + 'getSightseeing.php',
             type: 'GET',
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(){ alert("success");},
             error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
```

when i set the web_url as "`http://localhost/`" it's working, it can query the local db and return "success", but when I change the web_url as remote address like "`http://www.mydomain.com`", it's not working, I intentionally added the error code capturing, it always popup alert " Not connect.\n Verify Network.", but i am sure i have internet connection available, is there any setting i missed?

I manually open the page "`http://mydomain.com/getSightseeing.php`" in browser, the page is available, and it print out the json data that i need.

I am new to Jquery Mobile, anyone pls lighten me up, thanks.

Comment: Javascript has a same origin policy. requests to other domains are not allowed, unless CORS is enabled, or the request datatype is JSONP.

Comment: You can't do cross domain ajax requests

Comment: You are being caught by the same-origin policy that prevents cross-origin requests without proper CORS headers.

Comment: Just a search in stackoverflow would give you the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i google around and think it's due to cross site request constraint, as i have to query remote database, how to enable CORS?

Answer (score 0):

I have searched through the stack overflow and finally i can get it working by using "jsonp" method, now my jquery mobile site can view remote data.

But when i deploy it onto my android phone ( i use phonegap to wrap it), it failed to show anything on my phone, and no error also, anyone can help?